# Div region after navbar in a responsive way in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar and I want to add a div region with the contents of a page, lets say a paragraph or something. I want this div to be after the navbar. I used `margin-top:200px` but I am not sure if this is responsive or if it is a better way to achieve that.

[image]

I want this "I am on the left" paragraph to be under the navbar, is it a better way to achieve that without using margin-top?

Here is my html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="top:50px; background:none; border:0px; box-shadow:none;">
        <div class="navbar-inner">  
            <div class="container-fluid" >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portofolio</a></li>
                    <li><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"></img></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="content">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><p id="some">I'm on the left</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

and here is my css:

```
.content{
    margin-top: 200px;
}

#some{
-moz-border-radius: 24px;
-webkit-border-radius: 24px;
border-radius: 24px;
/*IE 7 AND 8 DO NOT SUPPORT BORDER RADIUS*/
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
background: white;
}
```

I tried:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-bottom: 19px;
}
```

but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You usually put a margin-bottom property for the navigation, as been done in most of starter templates offered by bootstrap found here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ .

One that might look close to yours is: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/

Comment: I tried `.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-bottom: 19px;
} ` but it doesn't work

Comment: As I understand it doesnt work with navbar-fixed, with navbar-static everything is ok.

Comment: yes, exactly, if you are going to make it fixed, you should use margins/paddings of the content itself.